# Bug or feature when trait property is overriden with different value

Tags: php, oop, traits, php-7, php-7.1

In [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.properties) we can read:

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued. Before PHP 7.0.0, defining a property in the class with the same visibility and initial value as in the trait, raised an E_STRICT notice.

There's also an example:

```
<?php
trait PropertiesTrait {
    public $same = true;
    public $different = false;
}

class PropertiesExample {
    use PropertiesTrait;
    public $same = true; // Strict Standards
    public $different = true; // Fatal error
}
?>
```

Let's play around with this and remove $different property and set different value to $same property (everything tested in PHP 7.1).

```
<?php
trait PropertiesTrait {
    public $same = true;
}

class PropertiesExample {
    use PropertiesTrait;
    public $same = 2;
}
?>
```

According to the docs it should cause fatal error, but in fact it doesn't. But as soon as we change for example `true` to `false` it will again cause fatal error.

It seems that it doesn't work exactly as it is described in documentation - it seems that some casts are made before comparison. However it could be very tricky because it could lead to some unexpected behaviour, for example:

```
trait PropertiesTrait
{
    public $same = true;

    public function message()
    {
        if ($this->same === true) {
            return "A";
        }
        return "B";
    }
}

class PropertiesExample
{
    use PropertiesTrait;
    public $same = 2;
}

$example = new PropertiesExample();
echo $example->message();
```

when analysing trait code, you would expect that `message()` method will return `A` as according to documentation it's not possible to override this property with different value but it seems because of casts in fact it is.

So the question is - is it a bug or maybe it's desired way it works and where  can we read in PHP manual about those casts for traits properties?

Comment: If you believe that it's a bug, then I'd recommend raising a bug report on [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/)

Comment: @MarkBaker I've finished with adding this as a bug and it seems it is - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be bug. I've reported it here:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74269

According to comment added:

> The conflict detection logic uses zend_operator's compare_function, which does loose comparisons. The original RFC doesn't say whether to be strict or loose but I think the intention is that it would be strict.